# Probability of empty bag of balls

Tags: probability

You have two bags, bag 1 has m balls, and bag 2 has n balls. You draw a ball from a bag with 50% probability until one bag is empty. What is the probability that bag 1 is empty?

I tried to draw some probability trees but I cannot find a general formula.
I see that there is something like $\frac{1}{2}^m +(m-1)\frac{1}{2}^{m+1}+...$

Comment: @ElieLouis I think the sum should run up to $n-1$, since $k$ is the number of balls removed from nag $2$ (there must be at least one ball left). Apart from that, I agree with your formula. However, I don't have a closed form yet. For $n=m$, you can check that $p=1/2$, as expected.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to update that $n-1$(I had updated it but deleted my answer). I assumed my answer was incorrect since I didn't get a closed form, so I had no confidence in my formula. Thanks :).

Comment: @Arthurim If you are ok, you can accept the answer and set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So let's think about this problem step by step. Denote $A$ the event of drawing from bag $1$, and $B$ the event from drawing from bag $2$.
We must get either $m$ times in a row $A$, or $m$ times $A$ and $1$ time $B$, $\cdots$, or $m$ times $A$ and $n-1$ times $B$, but the important thing is that the sequence should always end in $A$. Now, if we assumed there was no order, the probability of getting $m$ times $A$ and $k$ times $B$ would be $\frac{1}{2^k} \times \frac{1}{2^m}$. But there is an order. Say $n=2$, $m=3$. We can get something like $AAA$, or $BAAA$, or $ABAA$, or $AABA$. To find the number of possible combinations with $k$ events $B$,just think about it as choosing $k$ positions for $A$ between $m+k-1$ choices. So $\binom {m+k-1}{k}$

The probability is then
$$p = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom {m+k-1}{k}\frac{1}{2^{k+m}}$$

Comment: This probability is equal to $1/2$... see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3928177)

Comment: @JeanMarie not necessarily, because unlike in that question, here $m$ and $n$ may be different.

Comment: @peterwhy, My bad, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

A way is to solve by the **recurrence equation**:

$$p(m,n)=\frac12\cdot p(m-1,n)+\frac12 \cdot p(m,n-1)$$

by the table

$$\begin{array}{c|cc}
m\backslash n&0&1&2&3&4&...\\ \hline
0&-&1&1&1&1\\
1&0&\frac12&\frac34&\frac78&\frac{15}{16}&...\\
2&0&\frac14&\frac12&\frac{11}{16}&\frac{13}{16}&...\\
3&0&\frac18&\frac5{16}&\frac12&\frac{21}{32}&...\\
...&...&...&...&...&...&...\\
\end{array}$$

note that every element is the combination of the $\frac12$above element plus $\frac12$ leftelement.